# I want to delete data that do not serve me, and retrieve only the data from the link

Tags: python, html-parsing

Thanks to Ethernet connection from my laptop to a i40 from precia molen I can catch informations by typing this in the web :
http://192.168.1.101/ValPoids.cgx
This retrieves me a value of the weighing sensors. 
Thanks to python I wrote a little code like this that catch the informations I need. Whereas I get a lots of things that don't interest me so I want to delete it and only get the information of the weight.

This is the code written in python :

```
  import urllib.request
  import time

  while True :
      page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.1.101/ValPoids.cgx')
      print(page.read())
      time.sleep(1)
```

In the end the program display that :

```
 b'<form><text><id>ValPoids</id><value>     0.4 kg</value></text><text><id>info</id><value>FALSE</value></text><text><id>TypePoids</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>HorsGammes</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>Instable</id><value> ~</value></text><text><id>Etendue</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>Zero</id><value>&#160;</value></text></form>'

 b'<form><text><id>ValPoids</id><value>     0.5 kg</value></text><text><id>info</id><value>FALSE</value></text><text><id>TypePoids</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>HorsGammes</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>Instable</id><value> ~</value></text><text><id>Etendue</id><value>&#160;</value></text><text><id>Zero</id><value>&#160;</value></text></form>'
```

What I want is to only get the 0.5kg or 0.4kg evrytime i make my measurements.
I want to erase evrything else. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is the output an XML or HTML? By the way,if you are using Linux it would be better to avoid that while True and sleep (busy waiting) by using crontab to schedule this script as a task. If you are using Windows you can achieve that by using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I am on windows actually, sadly I would like to say because it is really hard to use python with windows and more with windows 10 ! :(

Comment: http://www.file-extensions.org/cgx-file-extension

Comment: The cgx file contains web page update script in XML file format.

Answer (score 1):

Use BeautifulSoup to get only the text of the elements.
Or you can use regex.
If you don't have BeautifulSoup you should install it first.

**pip install beautifulsoup4**

With BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
all_forms = soup.findAll('form')
for form in all_forms:
    print form.text
```

Comment: I can't install it. With : pip install beautifulsoup4 it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you ! I am waiting for your help

Comment: And tell me what OS you use

Comment: Ok, i have to go now. I think that you don't have installed pip. First of all you should install pip. pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python.
After you have installed pip, be sure that you know how to use it. After this, you will know how to install beautifulsoup4 with pip.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import time

pip install beautifulsoup4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
all_forms = soup.findAll('form')
for form in all_forms:
    print (form.text)

while True :
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.1.101/ValPoids.cgx')
    print(page.read())
    time.sleep(1)
```

It tells me that intsall is an invalid syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I try to find a solution and by this way you can easily erase the part of the result that you don't need :

You load the file with :

```
ln=open("your_file")
```

Then you read ln and you convert ln to a string thanks to this :

```
ln = str(ln.read())
ln = str(ln)
```

After the only thing to do is to replace what you don't want with nothing using this :

```
ln = ln.replace
```

Example :

```
ln=ln.replace("What you don't want","")
```

It would replace what you don't want with nothing.